# Strange behavior in README file rendering

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I am experiencing a very strange behavior in my project's README.md file. I have a numbered list of 3 items, and everything looks OK when viewing as a raw file. But, when viewing in its markdown form, the second item has the number 1. instead of 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the [project](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `tab` in front of the codes segment.

````
1. In your dependencies, add
    ```
        compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:1.0.1'
    ```

2. Add a FloatingSearchView to your view hierarchy, and make sure that it takes
   up the full width and height of the screen
````